# embed html images tkinter

Tags: html, python-3.x, tkinter, beautifulsoup

all. I am learning more about coding and tkinter and Python in general and I want to create a currency converter. I have got the converter working like I want, but I want to add the USD to EUR chart from this website into my GUI:

https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=USD&To=EUR

Can I please get suggestions on how to go about doing that?

I have already used

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_code = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
self.soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'html.parser')
self.result = self.soup.find('span', {'class': "uccResultAmount"}).string
```

to get some information from the website.

Thanks

Comment: What is the issue? Are you looking for help with getting the result, or creating the GUI?

Comment: I want help getting the chart and putting it into the GUI. Thank you

Comment: The chart is a canvas, its content is created dynamically. Not easy to recreate. They query the content of the graph but the result returned is in some encryption/obfuscation. Most likely the code that draws the chart is not very readable to find out how to interpret the graph content responds.